# when i run the jsp file,it is showing like that picture...pls give some instructions

Tags: jsp

http://postimg.org/image/vp16ta97d/

Can anyone tell me why it is showing like that?
Pls give me some instruction.

I already installed JDK also,but it didn't work.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`http error:503` states  The request was not completed. The server is temporarily overloading or down. Make sure that your server is up and then try access your JSP

For that run this in browser `http://localhost:8080`. You can check server.xml for your port information